# How to interpret e.g. pcov returned by numpy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: covariance, numpy

When doing parameter fits with mathematics frameworks as e.g. numpy, often a covariance matrix is returned. I wonder how to interpret these and if the following is right:

The entries of the covariance matrix after an optimization show:

- on the diagonal: the variance of the found parameters:

  - $Cov_{1,1}$ is large -> changing parameter 1 has no big impact on the quality of the fit, *"the fitter is not really sure about this parameter"*
- on the other elements:

  - if $Cov_{1,2}=Cov_{2,1}$ are large, parameter 1 or parameter 2 could be removed from the model function as it is expressible by the other one.
- often a strong covariance of two parameters comes with a strong variance too as many different parameter pairs can be found

Comment: Could you explain your criteria for determining when the coefficients of the covariance matrix are "large"?

Comment: @whuber: with "large" I mean values that are large compared to other covariance matrix entries or for the diagonal elements one can do the square root to have a measure of standard deviation that is in the same unit as the parameter and thus can be compared to it.

Comment: That sense of "large" has little meaning because it makes no comparison to the estimated values of the parameters.  For instance, suppose a parameter whose units are in meters has a variance of 100 (i.e., a standard deviation of 10 meters).  Compared to an estimated distance of 10,000 kilometers that variance is truly small, but compared to an estimated distance of 1 meter it is huge.